# Data Tables and Firebase Web

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, datatables, firebase-realtime-database

i have some problem when i code my web

here's the Html

```
<table id="user_data" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nama</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>No.Hp</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody id="table-body-pengguna">

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And here's the Script

```
$('#user_data').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'csv'
    ]
});
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("users");

rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var name = snap.child("name").val();
    var email = snap.child("email").val();
    var noHP = snap.child("noHp").val();
    var status = snap.child("status").val();

    $("#table-body-pengguna").append("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email +
        "</td><td>" + noHP + "</td><td>" + status + "</td></tr>");
})
```

And here's the output

https://ibb.co/bYzpOv

Why the Datatables not displaying properly? Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not displaying properly'? You need to provide us with the input data and what you're expecting to see in order for us to help.

Comment: https://ibb.co/bYzpOv, the data is in there, there are 3 records but the datatables said no data available and showing 0 of 0 entries even though there are 3 records displayed in the tables

Comment: This is because you're appending the rows manually instead of using DataTables. You need to either call `$('#user_data').DataTable({ ...})` again after appending the new rows, or you need to use DataTable's ability to take a JS array: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: yeah, i know. but how to call the data tables after completing appending rows? i tried to swap the script like this (http://oi64.tinypic.com/547ozb.jpg), but it doesn't work.

Comment: It needs to be inside the `rootRef.on('child_added', { ... })` block. It's an asynchronous callback.

Answer (score 2):

This should work perfectly

```
    rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
         var dataSet = [snap.child("name").val(), snap.child("email").val(), snap.child("blood").val(), snap.child("Phone").val(), snap.child("Location").val()];
    table.rows.add([dataSet]).draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

first you must to set datatable into var, for example var table=$("#tbl")....
later on child_added event `table.row.add({id:15,user_name:"Jacob",...}).draw(false);`

When you're creating the datatable you must to set name to columns.

```
"columns":[
        {name:"id", "data":"id", "visible":false},
        {name:"user_name", "data":"user_name"},
        ....
        ]
```